# Map Resets When Pie Chart Slice is Clicked

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report with a slicer for business unit which filters a map to show several locations within that business unit.  When you click on a specific map location, the "Test Fail Reason" pie chart filters to show data for just that location (expected behavior).  Additionally, when you click a pie slice on the "Test Fail Reason" chart, the "Test Fail Sub-Reason" chart filters to show just the data for that fail reason (also expected behavior).

However, the problem is, when clicking the pie slice in "Test Fail Reason", the map resets to show all locations in the business unit again and as a result the "Test Fail Reason" chart resets to show data for all the locations in the business unit rather than just the selected location.

[image]

**Goal:**
I would like to figure out how to keep the locations from resetting, that is, when a slice on "Test Fail Reason" is clicked, the "Test Fail Sub-Reason" should filter but, the "Test Fail Reason" chart should not change.

I've looked at the relationships between all of the items in the report and nothing should cause a filter on the map other than the business unit slicer.

Any ideas about how to make this work or suggestions on additional features to look in to would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to hold CTRL while selecting each visual?

Comment: I did but, I might not be understanding what you're saying.  When selecting multiple visuals, the relationships don't show up.  When holding down ctrl+clicking the pie slice, the same behavior happens.

Comment: Are you selecting the visual, or you the part you want to filter? If you use CTRL + click, your current selection/filter should stay the same, and the part you've clicked on should be added to the filter. See official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-multi-select

Comment: So... The goal is to click on the location, then fail reason pie slice and have both those remain unchanged then, the sub-reason pie should filter.  If I hold ctrl+click location and then ctrl+click fail reason slice, the same behavior occurs (all locations show and fail reason pie resets)

Comment: Yes, goal is clear. Good news and bad news: It works perfectly with the buildin map visual, but apparently the Esri map doesn't support the Ctrl+click (yet)...

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Test Fail Reason to the Attribute Slicer Custom Visual:

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380794?tab=Overview

Your selections will "stick" like they do with a Slicer.

OT but I would also change the bottom Pie to a TreeMap - Pie charts only work well with 2 categories.